# HashTable of files does not yield the PsIsContainer test on Values

Tags: powershell

```
$source = @{}
gci | %{$source.Add($_.FullName,$_)}
$source.getEnumerator() | %{($_.value).PsIsContainer}
```

Does not get me anywhere; but

```
gci | % {$_.PsIsContainer}
```

Does
I have resorted to using

```
$source.getEnumerator() | %{
if ((($_.Value).Attributes).toString() -eq "Directory")
   {
   ...
   }
```

}

Which seems kind of clunky

Why is it that PsIsContainer doesn't work on HashTable Values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does work for me when I use a more direct method of adding items to the table, though:

```
PS> $source =@{}
PS> gci|%{$source[$_.FullName] = $_}
PS> $source.GetEnumerator() | %{$_.Value.PSIsContainer}
True
False
False
False
False
False
False
True
False
...
```

This seems to be an artifact of using the `Add` method for putting things in the hashtable.

Comment: Wow, I am surprised to find you are totally right.  This is a PSv2 bug, both approaches work in PSv3.